# Removing multiple div tag from url loaded using class name from Android webview

Tags: android, webview

i have tried from various sources , to remove multiple div tag using className please help ..

```
final WebView abv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = abv.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    abv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    abv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                abv.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                        "document.getElementsByClassName('follow-us','header style-2')[0].style.display = 'none'; " +
                        "})()");
            }

    });
    abv.loadUrl("http://example.com");
```

only the first one works (i.e 'follow-us' --- div tag with the className(follow-us ) removed in my webview

Answer (score 0):

Put Like This:

```
 view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
     "document.getElementsByClassName('follow-us')[0].style.display='none'; " +
     "document.getElementsByClassName('header style-2')[0].style.display='none';" +
 "})()");
```

Answer (score 0):

there is an specific way.
try this:

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
             "var head = document.getElementsByClassName('classname')[0].style.display='none'; " +
             "var head = document.getElementsByClassName('classname')[0].style.display='none'; " +
             "})()");
            }
```